# Count the number of occurrences of a string over a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a validation if the user has filtered the particular column correctly.

My idea is that I will get the (1st) total visible rows and (2nd) get the total visible row which has the string "TKF*".

If 1st = 2nd then a code will be executed otherwise a notification will appear for the member to check the filter.

Now, I am having a problem on counting how many ROWS which has a string of "TKF*" in a visible ROW only. I tried CountIf but it still count the unfiltered rows which contains the string.
Below is the current codes I have:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim VRows As Integer
Set rng = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
VRows = rng.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).count - 1 'count of total visible rows

Dim TKFcount As Integer
TKFcount = Application.CountIf(Range("C1:C100"), "TKF*")

If VRows = TKFcount Then
'some code here
Else
'notify user to check filter
End If
```

I tried to search the net for some solutions but all I can find is that CountIf doesn't exclude unfiltered rows. Appreciate if somebody could enlighten me and advise an alternative?

Comment: Adjust your filter criteria so, that it hides all rows that do not meet the criteria `"TKF*"` and use `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, Range("C1:C100"))` to count the visible cells with data. Note to remove the header row from the range if one exists start in C2: `Range("C2:C100")`

Comment: The reason I need this is for validation purposes. Some users will not filter or may miss to filter and hence I want to get this countif for TKF and then compare to the total number of visible rows. If it matched then a code will be excuted, otherwise notify the user to filter.

Comment: So this is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked X but your actual problem is Y. Can you please [edit] and include your actual problem into the question? There are probably better ways to detect if the user filtered or not. Also you could force a filter with VBA (if that meets your requirement). Please give more information about your actual problem and maybe include a screenshot.

Comment: Well noted and I have edited to be more specific on the scenario.

Comment: What does *"if the user has filtered the particular column correctly"* mean? If you need to force a specific filter then don't let the user filter and use VBA to filter. • What do you mean by *"correctly"* what does filtered wrong mean then? Please be much more specific here.

Comment: Because the user needs to filter a lot of column before executing another VBA and one of them is the TKF* filter which the user most of the time forget to apply. I have considered forcing the filter of TKF using VBA as an alternative but I am just curious if there's a workaround on the problem I posted.

Comment: The workaround would be to loop throug the data in column C and test each cell for `TKF` and add `+1` to a counter each time. But also have a look at [advanced filters](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/09/07/excel-advanced-filter/) which make it easier than using auto filter.

Comment: I am thinking that looping will slow down the script in total so the workaround I thought of is to copy all visible rows to new sheet and then run the validation. If the validation failed, will delete the sheet and notify the member to check the filter again.

Comment: Well you can do that too, but I recommend to test which approach is faster. Then copying a big amount of data also slows down (test it).